# Whatsapp Cloud API - Account does not exist in Facebook Hosted API, please use /register API to create an account first

Tags: whatsapp

I am trying to send a WhatsApp message using Facebook graph API

https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/107858631967863/messages

with below payload

```json
**{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "name": "hello_world",
        "language": {
            "code": "en_US"
        }
    }
}**
```

But I am getting below error message ,

```json
**{
    "error": {
        "message": "An unknown error occurred",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 1,
        "error_subcode": 2593006,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Account Not Exist",
        "error_user_msg": "Account does not exist in Facebook Hosted API, please use /register API to create an account first.",
        "fbtrace_id": "ApD14BKT4ZcnAmQe7aMNBYH"
    }
}**
```

Comment: A ticket is already raised with Facebook 
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/3167192560166616/?join_id=f1363198102c62c

Answer (score 0):

You need to first register the number on WhatsApp Cloud API before you can begin messaging. Checkout their developer docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/registration

Note, you will need to add the number to the Business Manager account and verify it in the process first.